How do you import financial data from yahoo
I have been using the following code to retrieve data from yahoo finance for stock.
I have been using the following code:
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
ABEV = wb.DataReader('ABEV', data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2024-7-1')
ABEV

But instead of receiving the financial data. I am getting an attribute error. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post to include the error message you are seeing.

Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word traceback. You can surround the report with 3 before and 3 after to properly format the output.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78838678/pandas-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group

i cannot get that to work , getting the following problems:
NB:
pandas_datareader.__version__ : '0.10.0'
python: 3.12.2

from pandas_datareader import data as wb
>>> ABEV = wb.DataReader('ABEV', data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2024-7-1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/talkies/anaconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 213, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/talkies/anaconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py", line 379, in DataReader
    ).read()
      ^^^^^^
  File "/home/talkies/anaconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py", line 253, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/talkies/anaconda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py", line 152, in _read_one_data
    j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'


Here's an alternative that seems more stable, try and see if its of any use.
import yfinance as yf

ticker_symbol = "ABEV"

ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker_symbol)

info = ticker.info

for ki in info:
    print(f'{ki}:{info[ki]}' )

hist = ticker.history(period="1mo")
print(f"\nlast 5 days closing prices: {hist['Close'].tail()}\n\n")

